# Watir selecting from a dynamically built search list

Tags: unit-testing, watir, dynamically-generated

I am trying to select from a list of li elements that are dynamically aggregated based on search text as keys are entered.  The list consistently comes up and some of the time the function correctly allows me to click on the list item and proceed.  Other times it times out, early or late I can't tell.  I have used sleep statements, inserted key presses, and other methods to get around this without any more success than this statement.  Any ideas?

using Watir-classic

- this is my seed text for my search function *

  ```
  ie.text_field(:id, 'school_name').set "linc"
  ```
- it returns with a list of schools that includes LINCOLN ADAMS ELEMENTARY *

  ```
  ie.wait_until {ie.text.include? "ADAMS"}
  ie.ul(:class, 'searchResults').li(:text => /ADAMS/).click
  ```

code without my comments in it

```
ie.text_field(:id, 'school_name').set "linc"
ie.wait_until {ie.text.include? "ADAMS"}
ie.ul(:class, 'searchResults').li(:text => /ADAMS/).click
puts "school selected"
```

Comment: Try removing `ie.wait_until {ie.text.include? "ADAMS"}` and chain `when_present` into the next line `ie.ul(:class, 'searchResults').li(:text => /ADAMS/).when_present.click`.  And--in this case--posting the HTML snippet is helpful for reproducing the issue.

Comment: note that watir-classic is now officially deprecated, and you should try to migrate to watir-webdriver (which has now been renamed to watir). I agree with @orde's solution; you should avoid calling `text` on the browser.

Comment: Nice!  Here's a link to the documentation, which indicates that `watir-classic` is indeed deprecated: https://github.com/watir/watir-classic#status.   Tell your friends!  ;)

Comment: The only issue with changing to watir-webdriver(now just watir) is the attach method which I use consistently to grab the IE browser that my client requires us to use.

Comment: You can use the [`use`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Window#use-instance_method) method.

Comment: @orde, unless things have changed recently, I don't think `use` is equivalent to `attach`. Webdriver's `use` only lets you access windows opened by webdriver. Classic's `attach` lets you grab any open IE browser window (including ones opened by the user outside of Watir).

Comment: @Hopper, is this a custom built autocomplete control or are you using one from a specific library (eg jQueryUI)?

Comment: @JustinKo: You're totally right.  I forgot that `attach` in classic could arbitrarily access IE browser instances.  It's been a while...

Comment: its from a jquery.  I get the .click to work on it 15/20 times.  I watch the result come back and when it fails it looks like the drop down closes before the .click grabs it.